# Selenium chrome extension automation with list of numeric/alphanumeric values in a .txt/.csv file

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m27yx.png)

Here's a screenshot of the seleniumIDE. What I would like to accomplish is to create a Loop from steps 1 to 3 then step 4 needs to fetch the value from a .txt file that contains a list.

Ideally the list of values needs to be looped automatically and steps 1-3 will loop until the list has been completed.

An example to visualize what I am trying to do would be steps 6-8. Step 8 is a second interation of the test

Tried converting to python pytest and loop with python with a hard coded path to the text file and convert back to selenium readable file. no success

Tried seleniums conditionals statements with various store commands.